# Trouble with yaml syntax for CloudFormation condition function Fn::Join: | !Join to specify multiple resource arn values

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

Requesting help with yaml syntax for CloudFormation condition function `!Join` to specify multiple resource arn values.

I cannot figure out the correct yaml syntax to generate a valid json IAM policy.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

- CloudFormation Template (yaml):

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Parameters:
  AdminRoleHaveRLP:
    Type: String
    Default: 'Yes'
    AllowedValues:
      - 'Yes'
      - 'No'
  TestPolicyName:
    Type: String
    Default: test-service-role-policy
  TestServiceRole1:
    Type: String
    Default: test-service-role1
  TestServiceRole2:
    Type: String
    Default: test-service-role2
Conditions:
  AdminRoleHasRLP: !Equals 
    - 'Yes'
    - !Ref AdminRoleHaveRLP
Resources:
  Policy:
    Type: 'AWS::IAM::ManagedPolicy'
    Properties:
      ManagedPolicyName: !Ref TestPolicyName
      Path: /
      PolicyDocument:
        Version: 2012-10-17
        Statement:
          - Sid: ServiceRolePolicy
            Effect: Allow
            Action:
              - 'iam:AttachRolePolicy'
            Resource:
              - !If 
                - AdminRoleHasRLP
                - !Join ['', ['arn:aws:iam::*:role/', !Ref TestServiceRole1,',', 'arn:aws:iam::*:role/', !Ref TestServiceRole2]]
                - 'arn:aws:iam::*:role/*'
```

- IAM Policy Output When Parameter AdminRoleHaveRLP=Yes:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "iam:AttachRolePolicy"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:iam::*:role/test-service-role1,arn:aws:iam::*:role/test-service-role2"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Sid": "ServiceRolePolicy"
        }
    ]
}
```

- Expected Policy Output:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "iam:AttachRolePolicy"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:iam::*:role/test-service-role1",
                "arn:aws:iam::*:role/test-service-role2"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Sid": "ServiceRolePolicy"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: What are the definitions of `test-service-role1` and `test-service-role2`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The normal and easier way to to define your policy is with `Sub`, not `Join`:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Parameters:
  AdminRoleHaveRLP:
    Type: String
    Default: 'Yes'
    AllowedValues:
      - 'Yes'
      - 'No'
  TestPolicyName:
    Type: String
    Default: test-service-role-policy
  TestServiceRole1:
    Type: String
    Default: test-service-role1
  TestServiceRole2:
    Type: String
    Default: test-service-role2
Conditions:
  AdminRoleHasRLP: !Equals 
    - 'Yes'
    - !Ref AdminRoleHaveRLP
Resources:
  Policy:
    Type: 'AWS::IAM::ManagedPolicy'
    Properties:
      ManagedPolicyName: !Ref TestPolicyName
      Path: /
      PolicyDocument:
        Version: 2012-10-17
        Statement:
          - Sid: ServiceRolePolicy
            Effect: Allow
            Action:
              - 'iam:AttachRolePolicy'
            Resource:
              !If 
                - AdminRoleHasRLP
                - - !Sub 'arn:aws:iam::*:role/${TestServiceRole1}'
                  - !Sub 'arn:aws:iam::*:role/${TestServiceRole2}'
                - 'arn:aws:iam::*:role/*'
```

Comment: That worked, I thought I had tried that but must have looked it over. Thanks for your help!